# Get appointments from all Outlook calendars

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices, appointment

I'm trying to read appointments from Outlook calendar using ExchangeServiceBinding but my solution takes appointments only from "default" outlook calendar and don't read from "sub calendars/custom calendars". Do you know how to define rest of the calendars or do you know better solution which contains all calendars?

Critical part is that solution shouldn't contain MAPI because of next use in web service.

My current code:

```
private static List<List<string>> ReadCalendarEvents(string email)
    {
        List<List<string>> calendarEvents = new List<List<string>>();

        // Specify the request version.
        esb.RequestServerVersionValue = new RequestServerVersion();
        esb.RequestServerVersionValue.Version = ExchangeVersionType.Exchange2007;

        // Form the FindItem request.
        FindItemType findItemRequest = new FindItemType();

        CalendarViewType calendarView = new CalendarViewType();
        calendarView.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        calendarView.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(200);
        calendarView.MaxEntriesReturned = 1000;
        calendarView.MaxEntriesReturnedSpecified = true;

        findItemRequest.Item = calendarView;

        // Define which item properties are returned in the response.
        ItemResponseShapeType itemProperties = new ItemResponseShapeType();
        // Use the Default shape for the response. 
        //itemProperties.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly;
        itemProperties.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties;
        findItemRequest.ItemShape = itemProperties;

        DistinguishedFolderIdType[] folderIDArray = new DistinguishedFolderIdType[1];
        folderIDArray[0] = new DistinguishedFolderIdType();
        folderIDArray[0].Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.calendar;
        //
        folderIDArray[0].Mailbox = new EmailAddressType();
        folderIDArray[0].Mailbox.EmailAddress = email;

        findItemRequest.ParentFolderIds = folderIDArray;

        // Define the traversal type.
        findItemRequest.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow;

        try
        {
            // Send the FindItem request and get the response.
            FindItemResponseType findItemResponse = esb.FindItem(findItemRequest);

            // Access the response message.
            ArrayOfResponseMessagesType responseMessages = findItemResponse.ResponseMessages;
            ResponseMessageType[] rmta = responseMessages.Items;

            int folderNumber = 0;

            foreach (ResponseMessageType rmt in rmta)
            {
                // One FindItemResponseMessageType per folder searched.
                FindItemResponseMessageType firmt = rmt as FindItemResponseMessageType;

                if (firmt.RootFolder == null)
                    continue;

                FindItemParentType fipt = firmt.RootFolder;
                object obj = fipt.Item;

                // FindItem contains an array of items.
                if (obj is ArrayOfRealItemsType)
                {
                    ArrayOfRealItemsType items =
                        (obj as ArrayOfRealItemsType);
                    if (items.Items == null)
                    {
                        folderNumber++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (ItemType it in items.Items)
                        {

                            if (it is CalendarItemType)
                            {
                                CalendarItemType cal = (CalendarItemType)it;
                                List<string> ce = new List<string>();
                                ce.Add(cal.Location);
                                ce.Add(cal.Start.ToShortDateString() + " " + cal.Start.ToShortTimeString());
                                ce.Add(cal.End.ToShortDateString() + " " + cal.End.ToShortTimeString());
                                ce.Add(cal.Subject);
                                if (cal.Organizer != null)
                                {
                                    ce.Add(cal.Organizer.Item.Name);
                                }
                                calendarEvents.Add(ce);
                                Console.WriteLine(cal.Subject + " " + cal.Start.ToShortDateString() + " " + cal.Start.ToShortTimeString() + " " + cal.Location);
                            }

                        }

                        folderNumber++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return calendarEvents;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In EWS you need to query one folder at a time, for non default folders you will first need to find the FolderId before you can then query the appointments (or items) within a Folder. To find all the Calendar folders in a Mailbox you need to use the FindFolder operation and create a restriction to limit the result to folder with a FolderClass of IPF.Appointment eg

```
                // Create the request and specify the travesal type.
        FindFolderType findFolderRequest = new FindFolderType();
        findFolderRequest.Traversal = FolderQueryTraversalType.Deep;

        // Define the properties that are returned in the response.
        FolderResponseShapeType responseShape = new FolderResponseShapeType();
        responseShape.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.Default;
        findFolderRequest.FolderShape = responseShape;

        // Identify which folders to search.
        DistinguishedFolderIdType[] folderIDArray = new DistinguishedFolderIdType[1];
        folderIDArray[0] = new DistinguishedFolderIdType();
        folderIDArray[0].Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.msgfolderroot;

        IsEqualToType iet = new IsEqualToType();
        PathToUnindexedFieldType FolderClass = new PathToUnindexedFieldType();
        FolderClass.FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.folderFolderClass;
        iet.Item = FolderClass;
        FieldURIOrConstantType constantType = new FieldURIOrConstantType();
        ConstantValueType constantValueType = new ConstantValueType();
        constantValueType.Value = "IPF.Appointment";
        constantType.Item = constantValueType;

        iet.FieldURIOrConstant = constantType;

        // Add the folders to search to the request.
        RestrictionType restriction = new RestrictionType();
        restriction.Item = iet;
        findFolderRequest.Restriction = restriction;
        findFolderRequest.ParentFolderIds = folderIDArray;

        try
        {
            // Send the request and get the response.
            FindFolderResponseType findFolderResponse = esb.FindFolder(findFolderRequest);

            // Get the response messages.
            ResponseMessageType[] rmta = findFolderResponse.ResponseMessages.Items;

            foreach (ResponseMessageType rmt in rmta)
            {
                // Cast to the correct response message type.
                if (((FindFolderResponseMessageType)rmt).ResponseClass == ResponseClassType.Success) {
                    foreach (FolderType folder in ((FindFolderResponseMessageType)rmt).RootFolder.Folders) {
                        Console.WriteLine(folder.DisplayName);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

You also might want to look at using the EWS Managed API which will save you greatly time and the amount of code you need to write

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen, 
this solution looks promising however I cannot get it work because of the EWSProxy. Could you provide more info for me regarding the EWSProxy please?

Best Regards,
Martin

Comment: EWSProxy is just a prefix i used with the WebService reference I've removed that from the sample